# Get value of Observable<SomeObject> in an object

Tags: typescript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angular7, angularfire

In Angular I have an interface defined of a category. Because the categories have a nested structure (by defining a parent) I defined the following interface in category.ts:

Now, how can I get the value of the subCategories parameter in the template?

***the interface***

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Category{
    name: string,
    displayName: string,
    displayIndex: number;
    subCategories?: Observable<Category[]>;
    parent?: string;
}
```

***the compontent***

```js
...imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.less']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Category[];

  constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.categoriesService.all().subscribe((cats) => {
      this.categories = cats;
      console.log(cats[0].subCategories); // outputs: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator} => If I subscribe to it and console that, it outputs the desired values.
    });
  }

}
```

***the template***

```js
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p><a [routerLink]="['categories', cat?.name]">{{ cat?.display_name }}</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let sub of categories.subCategories | async; let j = index">
                {{ sub.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It shows only the queried top-level categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, use the `async` pipe after `category.subCategories` to ensure that the latest value emitted from `subCategories` is used:

`{{category.subCategories | async}}`

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Edit:

It looks like in your second ngFor, you mean to do `cat.subCategories | async` instead of `categories.subCategories | async`. That will ensure all subCategories of each category get displayed.

Comment: When I do that (within ngfor looping all top-level categories) nothing is shown and I am sure the top-level-categories has that 'subCategories' property with content.

Comment: I see. It looks like in your second ngFor, you mean to do cat.subCategories | async instead of categories.subCategories | async then. That will ensure all subCategories of each category get displayed.

Comment: whoa! ofcourse, those damn scopes in angular! Thanks for the help 

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!